# How to update a table colum with data from an array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table without an AI index. I had to trim data from a colum, and now I need to update with result from trim, but with the cod I have now, only updates with the same value, last value from that array.

```
$i=0;
while ($row = $column->fetch_assoc()) {
$arr[$i] = trim($row['profile_value'],"\"");
$db->query("UPDATE `vwfl5_user_profiles` SET profile_value='".$arr[$i]."'");
$i++;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what you want to do. specify clearly. your question is unclear.

Comment: you have no `where` clause, so you're updating every single record in that table. and since you're doing it in a loop, only the LAST value used in the loop will stay in the table, since you've now trashed all the previous updates.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need a loop for this. Just do it with one query.

```
$db->query("UPDATE `vwfl5_user_profiles` SET profile_value= TRIM( '\"' FROM profile_value)");
```

If you don't want to update every record, just add a WHERE clause with whatever criteria you used to get the results you are looping over.

```
$db->query("UPDATE `vwfl5_user_profiles` 
    SET profile_value = TRIM( '\"' FROM profile_value) WHERE... ");
```

Comment: OP is trimming `"` -> `trim($row['profile_value'],"\"")`, where MySQL's [`TRIM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) - [`Remove leading and trailing spaces`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

Comment: Oops, totally missed that second trim argument. Thanks, @Sean.

Comment: there is no unique id, and that user_id is not unique. I know how to use Where, but dosn't work in my case.

Comment: if you changed it from `...SET profile_value = TRIM(profile_value)` to `...SET profile_value = TRIM( '"' FROM profile_value)` you answer would be spot on. [`TRIM([remstr FROM] str)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1. Shouldn't you update a specific row? Ie: `` "UPDATE `vwfl5_user_profiles` SET profile_value='".$arr[$i]."' WHERE id=$row[id]" `` (given there is an id and is integer)
2. I think you can do that with [Trim Function](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php)

Comment: there is no unique id, and that user_id is not unique. I know how to use Where, but dosn't work in my case

Comment: I think you need a primary key even if it is logical and not declared in MySQL ie WHERE ```email='$row[12]' and name='$row[4]'```. Anything to indicate you are updating the specific row. Else, @DontPanic #1 solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should add WHERE clause with table primary key to identify each item in the db:

```php
$i=0;
while ($row = $column->fetch_assoc()) {
$arr[$i] = trim($row['profile_value'],"\"");
$db->query("UPDATE `vwfl5_user_profiles` SET profile_value='".$arr[$i]."' WHERE id = " . $row['id'] . "");
$i++;
}
```